# The Challange method does not redirect to the specified url

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, vk

I'm making a site with external authorization through VK, I've looked through a lot of examples, but I ran into one problem, in all examples redirection to `ExternalLoginCallback` happens through `Challange` method with provider parameters and url, but redirection happens not to specified url, but to `signin-vkontakte-token`, which is specified in `ConfigureServices`. What can this be related to?(It doesn't matter if you give me an answer with the specified provider or another one, such as Facebook)

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
{
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalLoginCallback), "Home", new { returnUrl });
    var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
    return Challenge(properties, provider);
}

[AllowAnonymous] 
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (info == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, false, false);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Typically those authentication schemes redirect to a single endpoint like "/signin-oidc", and then do a local redirect to the redirectUrl you specified. Do you not see it hitting that return URL at all?

Comment: After ExternalLogin method there is no redirection to ExternalLoginCallback, in the address bar there is a link like "https://localhost:5001/signin-vkontakte?code=****&state=****"